# How to open .net files in photoshop or another image editor

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there any way to open .net files in photoshop?

Comment: The filename extension can be completely arbitrary. What type of file is it? What application created it? More info please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [list of software](http://filext.com/file-extension/NET) which use `.net` as an extension - I would say no.